# How to extract key values from json message assigned to a string object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am converting XML message with attributes to JSON and assigning to a variable. Now variable `x` has the converted JSON message. Now I want to extract the key value pairs from that variable `x(string)`.

Please check the below details. XML Message is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OBJECT key="postorder" type="TEMP">
    <TEMP>
        <ROW order-version-id="1" 
             layout-type="2" 
             order-no="3" 
             order-action="4" 
             estimated-price="5" 
             orig-price="6" 
             quantity="7" 
             orig-quantity="8" 
             quantity-type="6" 
             trade-currency="7" 
             base-currency="8" 
             settlement-currency="9"/>
    </TEMP>
</OBJECT>
```

and I am converting it using fast-xml-parser and the output is as below

```
{
   "OBJECT":{
      "key":"postorder",
      "type":"TEMP",
      "TEMP":{
         "ROW":{
            "order-version-id":"1",
            "layout-type":"2",
            "order-no":"3",
            "order-action":"4",
            "estimated-price":"5",
            "orig-price":"6",
            "quantity":"7",
            "orig-quantity":"8",
            "quantity-type":"6",
            "trade-currency":"7",
            "base-currency":"8",
            "settlement-currency":"9"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and assigning it as `var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);` now result of string type has the converted JSON message. 
From result, I need to get base-currency values

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a concise example of what you have (your input), how `x(string)` looks like and what's the output you expect. Also, you shuold provide some of the code of what you have tried, so we can easily find what isn't working.

Comment: XML Message is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OBJECT key="postorder" type="TEMP"> <TEMP> <ROW order-version-id="1" layout-type="2" order-no="3" order-action="4" estimated-price="5" orig-price="6" quantity="7" orig-quantity="8" quantity-type="6" trade-currency="7" base-currency="8" settlement-currency="9"/> </TEMP> </OBJECT> and I am converting it using fast-xml-parser and assinging it as var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObj); now result has the converted json message. From result, I need to get base-currency values.

Comment: If you parse the code it will be easier to read for everyone

Comment: Updated it. please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further examples, I'm not sure if this is what you actually want, but as I understand:

You have this:

`let x = '{k1: v1, k2: v2, k3: v3....}'`

And you want to have this:

`let object = {k1: v1, k2: v2,...}`

The fastest way to do this would be using JSON.parse functionality:

```
let x = '{k1: v1, k2: v2, k3: v3....}';
let object = JSON.parse(x);
```

---

**EDIT:** In your specific example, you don't need to use JSON.stringify. You already have a JSON object, o access it like this:

```
let object = /*that parsed XML*/
let baseCurrency = object.OBJECT.TEMP.ROW['base-currency']; //this will give you the value as string
```

Comment: added the examples. please check

Comment: If I do not stringify I am getting the below output { OBJECT: { key: 'postorder', type: 'TEMP', TEMP: { ROW: [Object] } } } and the value I am getting is undefined. Could you please check

Comment: @siva If fast-xml-parser returns an object, this should work. Unless the object isn't exactly as you posted, check that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` function to convert the string to JSON object.

Hope the below example would help you get started.

```js
const x = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}';
const json = JSON.parse(x);

console.log(json.key1);
console.log(json.key2);
```

#### Updates (based on changes in question)

The result you get from the fast-xml-parser is a JSON object. You need not convert it into a string using `JSON.stringify`. You can use that object directly and get the `base-currency` value.

See the code below.

```js
const jsonObj = {
  "OBJECT": {
    "key": "postorder",
    "type": "TEMP",
    "TEMP": {
      "ROW": {
        "order-version-id": "1",
        "layout-type": "2",
        "order-no": "3",
        "order-action": "4",
        "estimated-price": "5",
        "orig-price": "6",
        "quantity": "7",
        "orig-quantity": "8",
        "quantity-type": "6",
        "trade-currency": "7",
        "base-currency": "8",
        "settlement-currency": "9"
      }
    }
  }
};

const baseCurrency = jsonObj.OBJECT.TEMP.ROW["base-currency"];

console.log(baseCurrency); // 8
```

Comment: Please check the below details. XML Message is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OBJECT key="postorder" type="TEMP">
    <TEMP>
        <ROW order-version-id="1" layout-type="2" order-no="3" order-action="4" estimated-price="5" orig-price="6" quantity="7" orig-quantity="8" quantity-type="6" trade-currency="7" base-currency="8" settlement-currency="9"/>
    </TEMP>
</OBJECT> and I am converting it using fast-xml-parser and assinging it as var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObj); now result has the converted json message. From result, I need to get base-currency values.

Comment: Please update your question with the above details. Also post the result from fast-xml-parser.

Comment: If I do not stringify I am getting the below output   { OBJECT:   { key: 'postorder',
     type: 'TEMP',     TEMP: { ROW: [Object] } } }

Comment: Yes, exactly. See the code in my answer. I have given the code to get ```base-currency``` value from this object.

Comment: Instead of using ```var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);```, all you need to do is ```const baseCurrency = jsonObj.OBJECT.TEMP.ROW["base-currency"];``` to get the ```base-currency``` value.

Comment: I have not used result and copied the same code and getting value undefined. var jsonObj = parser.parse(req.rawBody,options); // to convert xml to json
let output = jsonObj.OBJECT.ORDR.ROW['trade-list-id'];
console.log('Output ',output);

Answer (score 0):

First use `JSON.parse` function to convert the string to JSON object.

```
const object1 =JSON.parse(jsonstr) ;
console.log(Object.keys(object1));
```

The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

Comment: Updated the question with details. please check